# What I have to change or add to get the result from this script

Tags: php, mysql

I should Ask again this question because is hard to me and after correct some errors.

My problem is,I fail to query payment of John Jackson payed in 2013.

This suppose to be when I insert name=John Jackson, class=grade one, and year=2013, the query suppose to check in setting table the setting field values of  year= 2013 and subtract the amount payed by John from payment table of 2013.
Example:(fee_setting-school_fee,boarding_setting-boading,exampaper_setting-exam_paper,lunch_setting-lunch) of both 2013, from payment and setting table.

I have this two tables "payment and setting" 
payment table (used to store only payment information)

```
id  fname        class     school_fee boarding exam_paper lunch date        year
1   John Jackson Grade one 100000     300000   30000      1000  2013-12-12  0000-00-00
```

setting table(used to store actual payment of service per one year)

```
id boarding_setting exampaper_setting fee_setting lunch_setting  year       date
1  200000           30000             200000      180000         2013-12-18 NULL 
   300000           40000             300000      190000         2014-12-12 NULL
```

In setting table I put actual payment of certain service for one year so that when student pay example(school_fee) the fee_setting field in setting table will minus the amount of school_fee payed in payment table according to year posted.

Here php script Join two table in(year)fields;

```
  <?php include("../Connections/conn.php")?>                       
    <?php
    $fname="fname";
    $date="date";
    $class="class";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
    $class = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['class']);         

     $sql2="SELECT SUM(boarding)as boarding,SUM(exam_paper)as     
     exam_paper,SUM(school_fee)as school_fee,SUM(lunch)as lunch,fname,class
     ,date,year FROM payment INNER JOIN  
     setting.year,payment.year from payment setting ON setting.year=payment.year
     WHERE YEAR(date) = '$date' AND fname like '%".$fname."%' AND class like   
     '%".$class."%' AND year like '%".$date."%'"; 

    $q=mysql_query($sql2);  

      }
    else{
   $sql="SELECT * FROM payment";
   $q=mysql_query($sql);
      }
       ?>
```

This the form I use to input search information

```
<form method="post">
<table width="500" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Student name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" /></td>

<td>Class</td>
<td><input type="text" width="10" name="class" value="<?php echo $class;?>" /></td>


<td>Year</td>
<td><input type="number" name="year" value="<?php echo $date;?>" /></td>

<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
```

This the echo script

```
<?php
while(!empty($q) and $res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){   
?>
<tr>
    <td width="15%"><?php echo $res['fname'];?></td>
    <td width="8%"><?php echo $res['class'];?></td>
     <td width="10%"><?php echo $res['boarding_setting']- $res['boarding'];?></td>
     <td width="10%"><?php echo $res['exampaper_setting']- $res['exam_paper'];?></td>
     <td width="8%"><?php echo $res['fee_setting']- $res['school_fee'];?></td>
     <td width="10%"><?php echo $res['lunch_setting']- $res['lunch'];?></td>
    <td width="10%" style="border-width:medium"><?php echo $res['date'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php }?>
```

I don't know where am wrong until it doesn't produce any result without any error.

Comment: what is the goal of $_POST['fname']=mysql_real_escape_string($fname); and the like?

Comment: You should have the results stored in the `$q` variable. I don't see you attempting to `echo` or `print` that out anywhere. Also note, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used. Look into PDO.

Comment: What ever I use $q it doesn't produce any result

Comment: First off, if you are not seeing errors you should turn on error reporting - `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);' because here is a fatal syntax error that breaks your script - `while(!empty($q) and $res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){` It should be - `while(!empty($q) && $res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){`. It's `&&` not `and`.

Comment: Still not produce any info! Ahh

Comment: ok, next - `$_POST['fname']=mysql_real_escape_string($fname);` is not correct.  It should be `$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);` and similar for `date` and `class`

Comment: Your SQL looks wrong, you should `SELECT SUM(..)` and then `FROM setting INNER JOIN payment` right now it's probably returns a whole bunch of errors

Comment: I tried to change INNER JOIN but still the problem exist